# Why i got error after i've logged in apache airflow?

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, airflow

I want to login into Apache Airflow, however when I've logged in I got an error. But I have created user in Ubuntu. I dont know where's the problem and the solution of it. Anyone knows how to solve it? I've installed apache airflow 2.1.3 version in Ubuntu from Windows 10 OS, and I really don't use kubernetes or docker, and my SQLAlchemy version is 1.3.24

```
Something bad has happened.
Please consider letting us know by creating a bug report using GitHub.

Python version: 3.8.10
Airflow version: 2.1.3
Node: ANONYM
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: dag.last_parsed_time

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/auth.py", line 34, in decorated
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 551, in index
    filter_dag_ids = current_app.appbuilder.sm.get_accessible_dag_ids(g.user)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/www/security.py", line 298, in get_accessible_dag_ids
    return {dag.dag_id for dag in accessible_dags}
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3535, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3560, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/faustinaleo18/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: dag.last_parsed_time
[SQL: SELECT dag.dag_id AS dag_dag_id, dag.root_dag_id AS dag_root_dag_id, dag.is_paused AS dag_is_paused, dag.is_subdag AS dag_is_subdag, dag.is_active AS dag_is_active, dag.last_parsed_time AS dag_last_parsed_time, dag.last_pickled AS dag_last_pickled, dag.last_expired AS dag_last_expired, dag.scheduler_lock AS dag_scheduler_lock, dag.pickle_id AS dag_pickle_id, dag.fileloc AS dag_fileloc, dag.owners AS dag_owners, dag.description AS dag_description, dag.default_view AS dag_default_view, dag.schedule_interval AS dag_schedule_interval, dag.concurrency AS dag_concurrency, dag.has_task_concurrency_limits AS dag_has_task_concurrency_limits, dag.next_dagrun AS dag_next_dagrun, dag.next_dagrun_create_after AS dag_next_dagrun_create_after 
FROM dag]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have not initialized airflow.

Suggest you look at this link - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html

Comment: do you mean init db before launching airflow webserver? I've done it. But I'll recheck later

Answer (score 0):

In my case was in AWS MWAA where I was having this issue: because the Python DAG file was removed from S3 I was getting the reported error message.

Once re-uploaded the file in S3 in its original location it resumed working.